# Automatic interaction between API and secured 3rd party API

Tags: api, security, authorization, 3rd-party

I would like to create GUI + API that calls third party API as follows:

- third party API is consumed once a day by my API,
- GUI user doesn’t have to log in every day (eg. can log in only once every 30 days to request data from my API)
- design my API scalable

The flow of system:

1. desktop/browser GUI sends request with 3rd party API credentials to my API
2. my API prepares request to 3rd party API to get JWT token
3. after retrieving token the JWT is used to request data from 3rd party API and store it in database

Since each request for collecting data requires valid JWT token, I have come across a few problems on how to make API collect data each day **without any user interaction**.

Things I have thought of (and optionally reasons why I've rejected them - which may be wrong)

1. Since JWT is valid for 30 days by default, maybe I could store it in (for example) Azure KeyVault?
2. ...but on the other hand I feel uncomfortable storing JWT when it's not needed. Therefore, I thought of storing credentials for each client in database and reducing token's lifetime to (let's say) 5 minutes, so I have it just for the time it's needed. But if I was to store those credentials, afaik I should store them hashed (if I am not wrong - I won't be able to use them in request for JWT)

My questions are:

- if I am correct and ideas presented above are wrong - I would like to hear more remarks (just for self development)
- what is the proper way of designing application (my API in that case) so it can **securely** deal with credentials/JWT and **securely** prepare requests **for many days without user interacting with it**.

any remarks related to any aspect of such system are welcome